# How to gracefully await while object not changed (no work code required!)

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to gather your advice on the following problem:

**Task**

There are two microservices running A and B. At some time microservice_A will create a request message (or array of RequestMessage[]) which is an example "RequestMessage" and send it to microservice_B.

```
    public class RequestMessage
    {
        public Guid guid;
        public string result;
        public DateTime expirationDateTime;

        public RequestMessage()
        {
            guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            result = "no_result";
        }
    }
```

The way of getting a response is built in the way that there is a service class that implements the method, which will be called at some time after the request was sent. The call (of the function ResolveRequestedMessage()) will be performed under the hood and only function implementation lay on the developer.

```
public class RequestMessageResolver : IRequestMessageResolver
{
    public bool TResolveRequestedMessage(Guid Id, string result)
    {
        // find the Request e.g in Request[] by id, Implementation lay on the developer side and can be various.
        RequestCollection.Get(id).result = "resolved";
    }
}
```

**Problem**

The RequestMessage should be awaitable, however the interface of the RequestMessage is defined and cant be changed.
Microservise_A should not proceed to any further action (within the call scope, however still be valid for some other requests e.g status/error/etc) until it id not get the resolution of the requested message.

**My idea and thoughts**

1. First I tried to create a wrapper class that will have TaskCompletionSource and can be set from outside (example 1). This works but required a lot of extra wrappers to achieve the desired results.
2. Another idea is to modify the wrapper to implement INotifyCompletion instead of having TaskCompletionSource, but not sure if this will bring big overhead and make the solution complex for no reason - did not try yet.

Code Example 1:

```
public class RequestMessageWrapper
{
    public TaskCompletionSource<bool> completionSource;
    public RequestMessage requestMessage;

    public RequestMessageWrapper(RequestMessage requestMessage)
    {
        completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
    }

    public async Task GetResponseAsync()
    {
        // also need to be cancelled somehow if (DateTime.Now > requestMessage.expirationDateTime)
        await completionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Microservise_A should not proceed to any further action until it id not get the resolution of the requested message." Doesn't that contradict your awaitable-demand? Or are there other clients to `RequestMessage` that need asynchronouty? From what I can see you don't need an awaitable at all.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain  Microservice_A still will do some other duties e.g update, other clients, with state/errors/etc. So yes it should work asynchronously but wait for the response within the call scope. I probably modify my question thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Sure, but not *asynchronously*: While the request is performed, A won't do **anything** from my understanind: "Microservise_A should not proceed to any further action until it id not get the resolution of the requested message" I still cannot see if or if not A needs the request be awaitable at all.

Comment: I was probably lost in the explanation or I am using the wrong terminology.
The microservice_A basically still need to respond to some other messages for example to report its own telemetry or status if some of the clients will ask it, so I cant block it from doing other stuff it is suppose to do. But the particular Request should be awaitable with the scope it was called.

Comment: As I understand you want your microservice_a to do some work after microservice_b sends a response?

Comment: @Eldar correct. E.g If there will be method at microservice_A CanFileBeSaveInMemmory() and it expects the decision from microservice_B and not proceed with saving until it does not receive the decision. However microservice_A should be able to perform some basic duties and not be blocked.

Comment: Well, for that I would suggest a pub sub design rather than request-response. For your sample: You make a request to microservice_B to ask if a file can be saved in memory and then you don't await the answer instead you have event handlers that listen for the particular event and does the job when something arrives.